# socket.io - xhr-polling disconnects automatically

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I made simple app using socket.io and the xhr-polling transport. 
I found out that the server disconnect me after several seconds I stay connected.

This issue happens only with xhr-polling transport..
How can I fix that? am I missing something?

Comment: I switched to flashsockets by explicitly setting the transport (`io.set('transports', ['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling']);`) and that solved it for me; no idea why xhr-polling keeps disconnecting.

Comment: It disconnects and then connects again or just disconnects?

Answer (score 0):

From: https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO

> **SERVER OPTIONS**
>
> **polling duration**: defaults to 20 seconds
>
> The maximum duration of one HTTP poll, if it exceeds this limit it
>   will be closed.